# If I give a recipe to a chef will it be available only there or everwhere?

Tags: i-am-setsuna

If I give a recipe to a chef in *I am Setsuna*, will the food be available only from that chef or all chefs in the game?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the wiki](http://iamsetsuna.gamepedia.com/Cooking_Recipes) for recipes:

> "Food can be made at the Chef in each town with Cooking Materials
>   after obtaining the recipes."

As far as I can tell based off that, and the table provided where it shows the locations you get the recipe, once you get the recipe, it is for whatever Chef is in that town. (Granted you have the materials)